# What is the best way to clean a refractometer?

Tags: extraction

I just purchased a refractometer and the manual mentioned cleaning it very often and very emphatically.  So what is the best way to clean it?  It is a VST inc Lab Coffee iii Digital Refractometer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are instructions on maintenance and cleaning in the refractometers manual. However with distilled water and soft towels/tissues and/or Q-tips for the edges (be careful not to scratch the prism with the plastic handle) you can get rid of all the residue. Don't use alcohol or something like that. If the oils don't come off or if it's really dirty you could use a little bit of mild detergent in the water and wipe it with distilled water at the end to get rid of any detergent residue.

Comment: Why don't you recommend alcohol?  After I posted this, my wife pointed out that it came with alcohol swabs.  There is no where in there the manufacturers expound on what they mean by clean.  They simply say clean.

Comment: Thanks for tip on not scratching.  Did not consider that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alcohol swab to clean, but then always use distilled water, and then dry tissue/gauze directly after. I think this may clear up confusion.